# Table inheritance and Sequential scan in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Google cloud platform Cloud SQL with postgres 15 (2 CPU, 8GB RAM)

i have the following tables: address, warehouse, pudo, agency.

warehouse, pudo, agency have a PK+FK ID that references address.id (i'm using inheritance)

DDL:

```
-- public.addresses definition

CREATE TABLE addresses (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    address_type int2 NOT NULL,
    full_address text NOT NULL,
    information text NULL,
    place_id int4 NULL,
    zip_code text NULL,
    contact_id int8 NULL,
    latitude numeric(9, 6) NULL,
    longitude numeric(9, 6) NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    deleted_at timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT addresses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_addresses_place_id ON public.addresses USING btree (place_id);


-- public.agencies definition

CREATE TABLE agencies (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    code text NOT NULL,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    original_id int4 NULL,
    carrier_code varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    activated bool NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT agencies_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT agencies_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES addresses(id)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_agencies_code ON public.agencies USING btree (code);
CREATE INDEX ix_agencies_original_id ON public.agencies USING btree (original_id);


-- public.pudos definition

CREATE TABLE pudos (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    code text NOT NULL,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    original_id int4 NULL,
    activated bool NOT NULL,
    shipper_id int4 NULL,
    organization_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pudos_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT pudos_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES addresses(id)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_pudos_code ON public.pudos USING btree (code);
CREATE INDEX ix_pudos_original_id ON public.pudos USING btree (original_id);


-- public.warehouses definition

CREATE TABLE warehouses (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    code text NOT NULL,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    original_id int4 NULL,
    activated bool NOT NULL,
    shipper_id int4 NULL,
    organization_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT warehouses_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT warehouses_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES addresses(id)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_warehouses_code ON public.warehouses USING btree (code);
CREATE INDEX ix_warehouses_original_id ON public.warehouses USING btree (original_id);
```

However when i select addresses and do a left join against the other tables, a sequential scan is done instead of using the index, so i believe it results in a exponential query.

```
  explain (analyze, buffers, verbose, settings) SELECT addresses.id, warehouses."name", pudos.name, agencies.name
   FROM addresses
   left JOIN warehouses ON addresses.id = warehouses.id
   left join pudos on pudos.id = addresses.id
   left join agencies on agencies.id = addresses.id
   ;
```

results in the following plan

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=1703.57..129320.18 rows=3971277 width=54) (actual time=27.503..5095.065 rows=3970457 loops=1)
  Output: addresses.id, warehouses.name, pudos.name, agencies.name
  Inner Unique: true
  Hash Cond: (addresses.id = agencies.id)
  Buffers: shared hit=57168
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1693.57..118885.57 rows=3971277 width=38) (actual time=27.257..4021.037 rows=3970457 loops=1)
        Output: addresses.id, warehouses.name, pudos.name
        Inner Unique: true
        Hash Cond: (addresses.id = pudos.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=57165
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1622.12..108389.51 rows=3971277 width=23) (actual time=26.047..2857.830 rows=3970457 loops=1)
              Output: addresses.id, warehouses.name
              Inner Unique: true
              Hash Cond: (addresses.id = warehouses.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=57144
              ->  Seq Scan on public.addresses  (cost=0.00..96342.77 rows=3971277 width=8) (actual time=0.011..746.439 rows=3970457 loops=1)
                    Output: addresses.id, addresses.address_type, addresses.full_address, addresses.information, addresses.place_id, addresses.zip_code, addresses.contact_id, addresses.latitude, addresses.longitude, addresses.created_at, addresses.updated_at, addresses.deleted_at
                    Buffers: shared hit=56630
              ->  Hash  (cost=1006.50..1006.50 rows=49250 width=23) (actual time=25.906..25.908 rows=49263 loops=1)
                    Output: warehouses.name, warehouses.id
                    Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3283kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=514
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.warehouses  (cost=0.00..1006.50 rows=49250 width=23) (actual time=0.008..12.818 rows=49263 loops=1)
                          Output: warehouses.name, warehouses.id
                          Buffers: shared hit=514
        ->  Hash  (cost=43.42..43.42 rows=2242 width=23) (actual time=1.186..1.187 rows=2242 loops=1)
              Output: pudos.name, pudos.id
              Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 162kB
              Buffers: shared hit=21
              ->  Seq Scan on public.pudos  (cost=0.00..43.42 rows=2242 width=23) (actual time=0.038..0.551 rows=2242 loops=1)
                    Output: pudos.name, pudos.id
                    Buffers: shared hit=21
  ->  Hash  (cost=6.11..6.11 rows=311 width=24) (actual time=0.236..0.237 rows=312 loops=1)
        Output: agencies.name, agencies.id
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 27kB
        Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Seq Scan on public.agencies  (cost=0.00..6.11 rows=311 width=24) (actual time=0.015..0.077 rows=312 loops=1)
              Output: agencies.name, agencies.id
              Buffers: shared hit=3
Settings: effective_cache_size = '3259432kB', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'
Query Identifier: -50728131141259105
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=32
Planning Time: 0.628 ms
Execution Time: 5387.436 ms
```

ADDRESSES: 4 million rows
WAREHOUSES: 49 thousand rows
PUDOS: 2 thousand rows
AGENCIES: 311 rows

If i add a LIMIT or do some extra filtering then it uses the indexes.

```
Limit  (cost=2.25..488.09 rows=10000 width=54) (actual time=0.152..15.465 rows=10000 loops=1)
  Output: addresses.id, warehouses.name, pudos.name, agencies.name
  Buffers: shared hit=9058 dirtied=1
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=2.25..192945.01 rows=3971277 width=54) (actual time=0.150..14.036 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Output: addresses.id, warehouses.name, pudos.name, agencies.name
        Inner Unique: true
        Merge Cond: (addresses.id = agencies.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=9058 dirtied=1
        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=2.10..182993.56 rows=3971277 width=38) (actual time=0.108..11.266 rows=10000 loops=1)
              Output: addresses.id, warehouses.name, pudos.name
              Inner Unique: true
              Merge Cond: (addresses.id = pudos.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=9056 dirtied=1
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1.82..172904.97 rows=3971277 width=23) (actual time=0.093..8.809 rows=10000 loops=1)
                    Output: addresses.id, warehouses.name
                    Inner Unique: true
                    Merge Cond: (addresses.id = warehouses.id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=9053 dirtied=1
                    ->  Index Only Scan using addresses_pkey on public.addresses  (cost=0.43..160480.49 rows=3971277 width=8) (actual time=0.019..4.936 rows=10000 loops=1)
                          Output: addresses.id
                          Heap Fetches: 10001
                          Buffers: shared hit=8075 dirtied=1
                    ->  Index Scan using warehouses_pkey on public.warehouses  (cost=0.29..1880.66 rows=49250 width=23) (actual time=0.070..0.756 rows=1522 loops=1)
                          Output: warehouses.id, warehouses.code, warehouses.name, warehouses.original_id, warehouses.activated, warehouses.shipper_id, warehouses.organization_id
                          Buffers: shared hit=978
              ->  Index Scan using pudos_pkey on public.pudos  (cost=0.28..132.38 rows=2242 width=23) (actual time=0.014..0.039 rows=58 loops=1)
                    Output: pudos.id, pudos.code, pudos.name, pudos.original_id, pudos.activated, pudos.shipper_id, pudos.organization_id
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Index Scan using agencies_pkey on public.agencies  (cost=0.15..19.37 rows=311 width=24) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: agencies.id, agencies.code, agencies.name, agencies.original_id, agencies.carrier_code, agencies.activated
              Buffers: shared hit=2
Settings: effective_cache_size = '3259432kB', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'
Query Identifier: 1842408742140646225
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=32
Planning Time: 1.031 ms
Execution Time: 16.198 ms
```

The problem is that i have this query inside a subselect in a much more complex query, so it does sequential scans and slows down everything, i could try to optimize that query somehow, but is there some reason why postgres doesn't use the indexes??

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? And the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement. Just explain is not enough. And what version of PostgreSQL do you use?

Comment: @FrankHeikens edited the question with the ddl, the explain and the version (postgres 15 on cloud sql)

Comment: Most of the time is spent on the Hash Left Join's, not on the sequential reads. When you need all data, a sequential read is the best plan. I think this plan is caused by the data model, 3 tables that are (almost) the samen and could/should be just one table: warehouses and pudos have the same structure, and agencies is almost the same. Using a single table would give you just one left join instead of three.